# JSF restful output non-english characters

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I have a restful class to send JSON string to POST request. Data are store in DB with UTF-8 format. But the non-english characters always display as '??????', it all works fine if I get records form @Model.
Here is the code snap of rest (Using simple JSON to encoding JSON string):

```
@POST
@Path("/holidaylist")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getHoliday(){

    List list = new LinkedList();
    // Get list of holidays
    List<Holiday> holidays = em.createQuery("SELECT holiday FROM Holiday holiday").getResultList();

    Map event;
    for(Holiday holiday : holidays){
        System.out.println("======== Holiday name： " + holiday.getHolidayName());
        event = new HashMap();
        event.put("id", holiday.getHolidayId());
        event.put("title", holiday.getHolidayName());
        event.put("start", holiday.getStartDate().toString());

        list.add(event);
    }

    return JSONValue.toJSONString(list);
}
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: This often happens because the POST request specifies another character set. So the underlying mechanismes in Java-EE automatically convert what you requested to the character set that is acceptable by the POST request. If this request is coming from a webpage you may have to change the webpage to specify utf-8.

Comment: It's utf-8 format from webpage.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you properly handle data encoding all along, starting from the DB and to the front-end. I'm not totally familiar with the SimpleJSON api, but are sure the toJSONString uses UTF-8 encoding? Also, make sure your page where you render t

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using JAXB implementation. Seems simple JSON encoding issue.

Thanks everyone.